# External Pullup in Systemverilog Interface

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to model an external pull up in my interface.

```
interface inter();
  wire a;
  wire a_out;

  assign (pull1, strong0) a = (a_out === 1'b0) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
  // assign (pull1, strong0) a = a_out;
  // pullup p1 (a_out);
endinterface
```

So when `a_out` is 0, then `a` should be 0, but when `a_out` is Z, then `a` should be pulled up to 1.

Currently I am using `===` to compare, because primitives don't work in interface.

Is there any better way, as I believe usage of `===` should be avoided?

Also my main application is to use this net in a class task through virtual interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do any of this if you simply change the declaration of `a_out` to

```
tri1 a_out;
```

Comment: I am not able to use this `tri1 a_out` net in a class task, through virtual interface.

Comment: If you were using `wire` before, there's no reason you couldn't use `tri1`